# addthis and making sure page doesnt hang

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

I am just implementing Addthis social buttons onto my site, but I would like to create a fail safe method that would make sure that if by chance that the addthis_widget.js file fails or just hangs consistently trying to load it, that it doesnt cause my site to hang and not finish loading everything it needs to.

From researching online about this issue I have found this example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-520bd33b4d6dd146&domready=1"></script>
​<script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
    addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;

    function initAddThis() {
         addthis.init()
    }
    // After the DOM has loaded...
    initAddThis();
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to test if this will work or do what I want it to do. Was hoping someone could help me out in figuring out if this works.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use this `window.onload = function...` to launch it after the web page loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just load the script on the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-520bd33b4d6dd146&domready=1"></script>
</body>
```

That will make sure the rest of the page is loaded before It tries to load the add this script. Many people nowadays prefer this method.

After that you can call the init function in the document ready function. That will make sure the plugin isn't initialized before the page is loaded entirely.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initAddThis();
});
```